# Can I disable the gallery preview icon in the Galaxy S4's camera app?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, camera

The camera on my Galaxy S4 has a box in the top left corner of the screen which shows photos from the Gallery. How do I turn that off? I only want to be looking at the camera screen.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not do that with the stock camera application. Try some third-party applications from [Play Store Photography Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/PHOTOGRAPHY). May be you can find some luck there.
Edit -
Well I found this one for you. Have any luck? [Camera Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photo.android.camera)